# Run some modules on standard Python interpreter, others on IronPython

Tags: python, windows, ironpython, pytest

I'm using PyTest, a third party test library that doesn't seem to work with IronPython. How can I call modules that need to run on the IronPython interpreter from my modules that use PyTest that are running on the standard Python interpreter?

Comment: You might be interested in this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939678/pure-python-implementation-of-greenlet-api

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question again, it seems like I got it backwards. Python for .NET might be the solution, as it lets you import CLR modules from CPython. http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/. You can compile your IronPython code as a .DLL and import that.

It should also let you do the reverse - embed the CPython Runtime in your .Net application.

Comment: pytest doesn't use any c extensions, it's pure python, so that won't help at all.

Comment: @mata - Thanks for pointing that out. It looks like to embed CPython in .NET "Python for .NET" will do the trick. Although its a tenuous solution that will probably force you to downgrade version numbers.